# Dynamic values above column + jQuery Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

I'm working with a **stacked column chart** from **jQuery HighCharts** like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/72E7y/). (fiddle link)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked column chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -70,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 20,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                    'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [null, null, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [null,null, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
    });
});
```

As you can see there's the total number above each column of the total of the number. But I need something else. I want my first bar to be 100%. And then I need to calculate the percentage of the other 2 columns and place those numbers above the column. How can I make them dynamic?

Comment: So the first bar (3) should have 3 value (I suppose that yAxis is limited to 3), but other points (which includes i.e 4 and other values) should be translated / converted to smaller value, to achieve proportional value to first bar, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do here is extend the point properties and add in a new field that gets shown in the `dataLabels`. You would need to preprocess what these percentages would be of course. The following example assumes you have already calculated the percentage values:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.perc} %'
        }
    }
}
```

The `point.perc` is the point's `perc` property we made up and it contains the percentage values you calculated already.
In the data array you can have this format:

```
series: [{
            data: [{y: 29.9, perc: 100}, {y:71., perc: 50}, {y:106.4, perc: 30}, {y:129.2, perc: 20}]        
        }]
```

Live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/wS9wz/).